# Can a postgres check *conditionally* restrict duplicates?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, duplicates

I have to implement a rule that only one 'group' with a given ID can have status 'In Progress' or 'Problem' at one time. Is it possible to represent this in a Postgres check, or would I have to resort to logic in the application?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (1, 'In Progress'); -- okay
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (2, 'Problem'); -- okay
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (3, 'In Progress'); -- okay
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (4, 'Problem'); -- okay
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (1, 'Something else'); -- okay
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (2, 'Foo bar'); -- okay

INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (1, 'In Progress'); -- should fail
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (1, 'Problem'); -- should fail
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (2, 'In Progress'); -- should fail
INSERT INTO group (group_id, status) VALUES (2, 'Problem'); -- should fail
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a partial unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX group_status_unq_idx 
ON "group"(group_id, status) WHERE (status IN ('In Progress', 'Problem'));
```

However, it isn't clear to me from your description why the second expected-failure would fail. Do you want to allow *only one of `In Progress` or `Problem` for any given `group_id`*? If so, you could write something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX group_status_unq_idx
ON "group"(group_id) WHERE (status IN ('In Progress', 'Problem'));
```

... omitting the `status` from the partial unique index and using it only for the predicate. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/03606/2).

Note that this cannot be expressed as a `UNIQUE` constraint, since unique constraints do not take a predicate. A PostgreSQL unique constraint is *implemented using* a (non-partial) `UNIQUE` index, but it also creates metadata entries that the mere index creation does not. A partial unique index works like a unique constraint with a predicate, but it won't be discoverable via metadata like `information_schema`'s constraint info.

Comment: At the risk of being chatty: nifty, nifty, nifty!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
create unique index group_restriction_index on group
(status) where status in ('In Progress', 'Problem')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a unique constraint on multiple columns:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    group_id integer,
    status char(100),
    UNIQUE (group_id, status)
);
```

(From the [Postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html)).

This would prevent duplicates for any status, though, not just `'In Progress'` and `'Problem'`.  I'm not sure if that is what you want.